Sudden ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR on every JS and CSS files loads
I recently went on my website which is online since more than 5 years now and realized that none of the CSS and JS files were loading. By looking into the console, I’ve seen that every load fails because of a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. And when i try to open whichever file that is supposed to be loaded, I have the same error as well in the console and nothing loads.
An even stranger thing is that it seems that this happens on laptop, either mac or windows (as I tested the two) in any browser, but it works as normal on every mobile phones, on every browsers.
For info, I had recently (like one week ago) done some Litespeed settings changes but now i purged all the cache, put the settings back to normal and re purged all but nothing. In addition, when I try to go to the Really Simple SSL plugin I can’t do anything cause it is greyed, as the admin panel also has some JS and CSS problems.
Does someone already had something like that or knows how to fix it ?
Thanks in advance !
Best regards

What's the URL?  This may be a network thing on your end.  What happens if you access the site outside of your LAN?

Thanks for your reply ! Finally found out that it was a problem of IpXtender that was messing up the css/js load !
